# Pos terminal rebooting

Tags: c

Am using armcc and vc6 to program a C base POS device and Have been trying to figure out why on call to the function "encrypt"(Just as i did in the main method) my pos terminal reboot(restart itself). could someone please help. thank in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_CIPHER_SIZE         512
#define  MAX_T_SIZE             30

char cipher[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE];
char ca[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE];
int ct[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE];
char Body[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE];

char Token[MAX_T_SIZE+1];

int len;
int n = 253;
int e = 13;

void encrypt(char *plainText, char *cipher, int len)
{
    int c;
    int k;
    int j;
    int i;

    k=1;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        c= plainText[i];
        for (j = 1; j <= e; j++)
        {
    k = (k * c) % n;
        }
        ct[i] = k;
        sprintf(ca,"%d", ct[i]);
        strcat(cipher, ca);
        if(i+1 < len)
        {
            strcat(cipher,",");
        }

    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *pCode = "6543";
    char *pPassword = "2341";
    sprintf(Body,"%s#%s#%s","1",pCode, pPassword);
    len = strlen(Body);
    encrypt(Body, cipher, len);
    printf("cypher text = %s\n",cipher);
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```